# Different sub-population sizes in grading data

Tags: contingency-tables

I am relatively new to statistical analysis.

Let's say I have a data set of 5000 report card grades

- 3000 (60%) are "A" grades
- 100 (2%) are "D" grades and
- 25 (0.5%) are "F" grades

and let's also say that there are demographic data for who received the grades.

- 65% of grades went to category X
- 35% of grades went to category Y

Should it be expected that 65% of "A" Grades go to category X and 35% to category Y  and would the same be true for "F" grades (despite wildly different sizes of "A" vs "F") are they even comparable when one group is 3000 and the other is 25?

If the grades aren't the same as the demographics  (say 70% of "A"s go to X and 30% go to Y and a 50/50 split for "F" grades) is there a test or method to see if it's within an acceptable amount of "wiggle room" (non-statistical term)?

Answer (score 0):

this would be called a contingency table and the test used to test the association in this case would usually be a chi squared test or fisher's exact test.